No network connection creation options on Ubuntu 20.04
I'm trying to establish an ad-hoc network for file transfer between two tower PCs running desktop Ubuntu: One running 20.04.6 (source PC) and the other running 24.04.1 (destination PC; might wind up being a Mint system if 24.04 keeps giving me problems).
Every set of instructions I can find says to create and/or configure the connection settings in the network applet for 20.04, but I don't have any of the relevant options available:

For a wifi connection I believe I'm supposed to have a "Edit connections" or "Create new wireless network" option and I don't have either.
A wired connection isn't an option since the 20.04 PC doesn't recognize the hardware port for some reason (eth0 doesn't exist at all, similar to this post).
I tried turning on the wifi hotspot but it didn't seem to enable file transfer. network-manager-gnome is installed and I tried nmcli networking on and then off again with no change. Am I missing something?
